# Disable "Save Password" Dialog in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, jsx

I am using a TextInput with with the `secureTextEntry` flag to allow users to enter their password. When I run my `tryLogin()` function, iOS will ask if the user wants to "remember the password on the browser" (similar to how Safari does it), regardless if the password is correct or not.

Is there any way to disable that dialog box in React Native?

Comment: Can you please share code of your `TextInput`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was dumb of me: `<TextInput 
      autoCapitalize="none" 
      placeholderTextColor={appColors.lightGray} 
      style={styles.input} 
      autoCorrect={false} 
      placeholder="Password" 
      secureTextEntry={true} 
      keyboardType="email-address"
      ref = {component => this.inputs.LIPass = component}
      returnKeyType="done"
      value={this.state.loginPass}
      textContentType="none"
      onChangeText={(pass) => this.setState({loginPass: pass})}
     />`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure the **textContentType** 
here's the reference link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#textcontenttype

Hope this help :)

Comment: unfortunately this only helps with auto-fill, not whether or not it asks to save the password after submitting

Answer (score 0):

System modal "Save Password" shown when screen has "login" and "password" inputs, f.e

```
    <TextInput
      value={email}
      textContentType="none"
      onChangeText={setEmail}
    />
    <TextInput
      value={password}
      textContentType="none"
      onChangeText={setPassword}
      secureTextEntry
    />
```

if we remove secureTextEntry from password input or if we remove email input, then modal not shown.
That is, in order for the system modal not to be displayed, you need to “destroy” the login-password conditional connection. I found a workaround - mark these fields as fields that can accept code from SMS:

```
    <TextInput
      value={email}
      textContentType="none"
      onChangeText={setEmail}
      textContentType="oneTimeCode"
    />
    <TextInput
      value={password}
      textContentType="none"
      onChangeText={setPassword}
      secureTextEntry
      textContentType="oneTimeCode"
    />
```